# <script> tag elements are not working on Angular 2 CLI created application

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

I have create an application using angular cli. My application is the angular 2 application. I would like to run a `<script>` and put an alert box.

I have try to load the `<script>` on hello.component.html but it does not work. And also I try put the `<script></script>` inside the index.html but it also fails.

How do i implement `<script></script>` on angular 2 applications.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    alert("Hello from JS");
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you not declaring this functionality inside angular? Also `$('document').ready()` is only available if you use jQuery, is that the case?

Comment: I have reference the jQuery on `angular-cli.json` and I would like to show a dialog on page load using the jQuery way inside the internal script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<script>` tags in Angular2 component templates are just silently stripped.

You can use

```
class MyComponent {
  ngAfterContentInit() {
    alert("...");
  }
```

or add JavaScript to your TypeScript by other means like `require`

Comment: how we add the jQuery code to the ngAfterContentIniti()

Comment: Try to avoid jQuery with Angular2. There are lots of questions about how to use jQuery with Angular2. I don't know because I haven't tried.

Comment: @nifCody if it's already imported, you just do this on the top of your `.ts` file: `declare var jQuery:any;` and you can use `jQuery('document').ready();` later on.